# Handling CAMEL Mail exception

Tags: email, exception, apache-camel, imap, blueprint-osgi

i'm trying to catch Exception in CAMEL, when there is no connection, like this :

```
<from uri="imap://Uri"/>
   <onException>
    <exception>javax.mail.MessagingException</exception>
            <exception>java.net.NoRouteToHostException</exception>
   <handled>
        <constant>true</constant>
    </handled>
    <transform>
        <simple>Error reported: ${exception.message} - cannot process this message.</simple>
    </transform>
</onException>
```

But it dont work. I got this error message:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: No route to host: connect;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is from the consumer, eg the `<from>` then you need to bridge the error handler from the consumer.

See this FAQ:

- http://camel.apache.org/why-does-my-file-consumer-not-pick-up-the-file-and-how-do-i-let-the-file-consumer-use-the-camel-error-handler.html

The bridge option is also possible for the mail component.